# Tensorflow is working in python shell but not in python file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow. I installed it using pip install. The thing is when I enter this code in python shell, it works

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

but when I enter the same code in Idle, it imports the tensorflow module but gives error in the next line that

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

what could be possibly the reason?

Comment: check if you have tensorflow.py inside current working directory. os.listdir(".") may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I made a stupid mistake, I named the file that I was creating as tensorflow.py, which obviously was conflicting with actual tensorflow file. This was causing the bug. Comment from @Mitiku made my realize my mistake.